# How to add elements to an empty array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

If I define an array in PHP such as (I don't define its size):

```php
$cart = array();
```

Do I simply add elements to it using the following?

```php
$cart[] = 13;
$cart[] = "foo";
$cart[] = obj;
```

Don't arrays in PHP have an add method, for example, `cart.add(13)`?

Answer (score 1054, accepted):

Both [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) and the method you described will work.

```
$cart = array();
$cart[] = 13;
$cart[] = 14;
// etc

//Above is correct. but below one is for further understanding
$cart = array();
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
    $cart[] = $i;  
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($cart);
echo "</pre>";
```

Is the same as:

```
<?php
$cart = array();
array_push($cart, 13);
array_push($cart, 14);

// Or 
$cart = array();
array_push($cart, 13, 14);
?>
```

Comment: As stated in the PHP documentation, if you're only pushing a single element every time (like in a loop) or a single element once, it's best to use the `$cart[] = 13` method not only because it's less characters to do the same operation, but it also doesn't impose the performance overhead of a function call, which array_push() would.  Edit: But, great answer. Effectively the same, and majority of uses won't even notice a performance difference, but helps to know those nuances.

Comment: Is it just me or does the `$cart[]=...` syntax, at first glance, look like a variable assignment and not an implicit array_push?

Comment: It definitely does to me. I wouldn't mind an explanation of why its **not** an assignment.

Comment: $cart[] = 13; is faster. has less characters and looks better.

Comment: What is this alternate method? Is that a secret method? Syntactical overload?

Comment: I'll just offer my alternative viewpoint that it's VERY confusing for other language programmers to read the syntax of cart[] =..., I've got experience with a lot of languages and I'd never guess that's what it does.

Comment: Just to add on to what @Mattygabe said about the shorthand - the element can be any object that PHP is happy to put into an array. This is probably stating the obvious, but I figured I'll add that in here too.

Comment: @BrassApparatus If is an assignment, you are assigning to the new last element of this array. Did you mean a "plain" assignment? Well, it does have the indexer operator `[]` ?

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa It wouldn't hurt if other languages picket it up. Is it better in python: `a[len(a):] = [newVal] `?

Comment: Mattygabe's opinion could be doubtful, because optimization is required when it really pays off and not in every case (as per Steve McConnell). Readability and non-frustrainability of code is often much more important. Experimental facts from tests in loop are needed to say that `=` should be prefered to `array_push`.

Comment: @wolfdawn I don't disagree with your idea about other languages picking this syntax up, but in python you can simply call `a.append(new_val)` or `a.push(new_val)` for a list.

Comment: As an array can never be used for print with [ ], everytime you use like that, I mean empty, it means add to specified array. If you put a value, like [$x] or [3] than you specify a key, to read from array. Is that simple.

Comment: @AturSams I would use array_push any time (for readability) over the 2nd syntax (for micro optimization). In all languages I know, including PHP itself, array[index] = value; is an assignment. How come removing the index means adding new value at the end of the array? PHP syntax is weird sometimes...

Answer (score 107):

It's better to not use [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) and just use what you suggested. The functions just add overhead.

```
//We don't need to define the array, but in many cases it's the best solution.
$cart = array();

//Automatic new integer key higher than the highest 
//existing integer key in the array, starts at 0.
$cart[] = 13;
$cart[] = 'text';

//Numeric key
$cart[4] = $object;

//Text key (assoc)
$cart['key'] = 'test';
```

Comment: "If you're adding multiple values to an array in a loop, it's faster to use array_push than repeated [] = statements" http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php#84959

Comment: Absolutely correct if your use-case is adding a single item or items one at a time.  If all values are known at the same time, it's probably best just to use the array_push notation depending on how many items must be added the extra characters from re-typing the array name each time may be more of a performance hindrance than the function call over-head.  As always, judgment should be exercised when choosing.  Good answers!

Comment: This answer is the most complete.

Comment: 1) `array_push()` has a *return value*, whereas the others do not.  Perhaps this is the/one reason for its overhead? It seems to be a consensus to use the other methods, unless you need that return value.  2) *If you need elements to be added to the **end** of the array*, use either `array_push()` or `+=` method of concatenation (not shown in this answer), or `$cart[] = 13` methods. Using the named/numeric key method (`$cart[4] = $object` and $cart['key'] = 'test'` methods do not *guarantee* the element will be added to the *end* of the array, only that it will be *in* the array.

Comment: @SherylHohman: This $cart[] = will add values to the end of the array.

Answer (score 21):

Based on my experience, solution which is fine(the best) when keys are not important:

```
$cart = [];
$cart[] = 13;
$cart[] = "foo";
$cart[] = obj;
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [array_push](http://www.php.net/function.array-push).
It adds the elements to the end of the array, like in a stack.

You could have also done it like this:

```
$cart = array(13, "foo", $obj);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$cart = array();
$cart[] = 11;
$cart[] = 15;

// etc

//Above is correct. but below one is for further understanding

$cart = array();
for($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++){
          $cart[] = $i;  

//if you write $cart = [$i]; you will only take last $i value as first element in array.

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($cart);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: $cart[] = $i;  - that part of code add elements to array ---->
$cart = [$i];  - this will pass compiler but you will not get what you want

Answer (score 4):

REMEMBER, this method overwrites first array, so use only when you are sure!

```
$arr1 = $arr1 + $arr2;
```

([see source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2140094/2165415))

Comment: Why the downvote, can someone explain why this is bad? is it insecure?

Comment: @SandyBeach it's not an answer

Answer (score 2):

```
$products_arr["passenger_details"]=array();
array_push($products_arr["passenger_details"],array("Name"=>"Isuru Eshan","E-Mail"=>"isuru.eshan@gmail.com"));
echo "<pre>";
echo json_encode($products_arr,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo "</pre>";

//OR

$countries = array();
$countries["DK"] = array("code"=>"DK","name"=>"Denmark","d_code"=>"+45");
$countries["DJ"] = array("code"=>"DJ","name"=>"Djibouti","d_code"=>"+253");
$countries["DM"] = array("code"=>"DM","name"=>"Dominica","d_code"=>"+1");
foreach ($countries as $country){
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($country);
echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to append to an associative array

```
//append to array   
$countries["continent"] = "Europe";
```

Answer (score -1):

When one wants elements to be added with zero-based element indexing, I guess this will work as well:

```
// adding elements to an array with zero-based index
$matrix= array();
$matrix[count($matrix)]= 'element 1';
$matrix[count($matrix)]= 'element 2';
...
$matrix[count($matrix)]= 'element N';
```