# Add new array to Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, addition

```
 $shop = array( array("aaa", 1.25 , 15),
                array("bbb", 0.75 , 25),
                array("ccc", 1.15 , 7) 
              );    

 for ($row = 0; $row < 3; $row++) {
     for ($col = 0; $col < 3; $col++) {
         echo $shop[$row][$col] . "/";
     }
 }
```

Result:

> aa / 1.25 / 15 / bbb / 0.75 / 25 / ccc / 1.15 / 7 /

---

How can I add a new array in this array?

For example:

> array("ddd", 1.30 , 9)

Comment: Aren't you doing that in the first line itself?

Comment: `$shop[] = array("ddd", 1.30 , 9);` or `array_push($shop, array("ddd", 1.30 , 9));`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add elements to an empty array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676677/how-to-add-elements-to-an-empty-array-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by doing
`$shop[] = array("ddd", 1.30 , 9);`

Answer (score 0):

Most languages have a method built in to push on to the array. PHP specifically can do it thusly:

```
array_push($shop, array("ddd", 1.30 , 9));
```