# json encode value issue

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I know this is basic but i don't know what else i can do. So i need your help. Ill tell you what happened.

The story is that i have a database request and I want to json encode the data from that request and use it through a javascript file (`$.ajax` or `$.json`).

the data i need from that request are two values. Latitude and longitude. but when i receive the `json_encode` from php and put it in the console log or an alert it displays undefined instead of the "double precision"(because the json string).

Ill show you the code.

the php

```
    <?php
$dbconn3 = pg_connect
    ("host= localhost port=5432 dbname=EmergenciesResponse    user=postgres password=asdf");                


    $query1=pg_query
    ("select latitude, longitude from emergency where   id_emergency=5");

    $arreglo=array();
              while($reg=pg_fetch_assoc($query1)){
               $arreglo[]=$reg;

             }

              echo json_encode($arreglo);  

             pg_close($dbconn3);

              ?>
```

Then the `.js` code

```
 $.ajax({                                      
          url: 'consulta2.php',                  
          data:{
                },                        
          method: 'POST',                               
          dataType:'json',                
          success: function(data)          
          {                   
              alert("latitude:"+data.latitude+"longitude:"+data.longitude);        


          }
        });
```

As I said when I do an alert instruction the output prints undefined but the string of the php is correct. Sorry if its very easy but I don't know what to do about the undefined value

thx for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP returns an **array** of objects. The response will look like this (without pretty print):

```
[
    {
        "latitude": 0.000,
        "longitude": 0.000
    },
    {
        "latitude": 1.000,
        "longitude": 2.000
    },
    {
        "latitude": 3.000,
        "longitude": 4.000
    }
]
```

However, in JS you are treating is as **an object**.

You would understand what the problem is if you simply opened your `consulta2.php` file and looked at the response.

### There can be two causes:

1. `id_emergency` is **not unique**. Then, your PHP is good, but in JS you need to iterate through the array:

   ```
   $.ajax({                                      
       url: 'consulta2.php',                  
       data:{
       },                        
       method: 'POST',                               
       dataType:'json',                
       success: function(data)          
       {  
           $.each(data, function() { // <-------
                   alert("latitude:"+this.latitude+"longitude:"+this.longitude);
           });
       }
   });
   ```

   You will get **from 0 to many alerts**, one for every pair of coordinates.
2. `id_emergency` is **unique**. Then, your JS is good, but in PHP you do not need to form an array. It should be as simple as:

   ```
   $query1=pg_query("select latitude, longitude from emergency where   id_emergency=5");

   //$arreglo=array(); // don't need an array

   $reg = pg_fetch_assoc($query1); // only 1 object
   echo json_encode($reg); // encode the object, but not an array

   pg_close($dbconn3);
   ```

   As this is the single object, you will get only **one alert**.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this really helped me. Now I have to figure out how to make the same idea for multiple data.

Greetings from chile

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in your while loop, I think you are overwriting the same index in the loop, you should be increment the index at each iteration.

```
var counter = 0;
while($reg=pg_fetch_assoc($query1)){
    $arreglo[counter]=$reg;
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: No, it's ok. `$arreglo[]` will push the item into the array.

Comment: Please, read this StackOverflow topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676677/how-to-add-elements-to-an-empty-array-in-php

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Didn't know that. Thanks for the link :)