# Pushing into a 2 dimensional array in php

Tags: php

If i have an array with 2 dynamic values like this :

```
 $people = array(
    "george" => "smith"
);
```

How can i push into that in php?

I have tried

```
array_push($people, "john" => "smith");
```

EDIT :

I have tried what has been commented but adding a new key doesnt create a new entry in the array, there is only 1 value although there should be 3..

```
 $people = array();

foreach ($items as $item){

    $name = $item->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0);
    $num = $item->getElementsByTagName('number')->item(0);
    $mess = $item->getElementsByTagName('message')->item(0);

    if($name != NULL && $num != NULL && $mess != NULL){
        $people[$num->textContent] = $name->textContent;

    }

}
 var_dump($people);
```

Comment: ... What? What do you mean with "push into that"? You wanna add another value?

Comment: to which array do you want to push? give us a code that you have tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/676703/3933332

Comment: The names come in dynamically so it would end up  $people = array(
    "george" => "smith", "george2" => "smith2"
);

Comment: Google php arrays and find out how arrays function. - And the array you have demonstrated so far, is not a 2 dimensional array, it's a simple flat array.

Answer (score 2):

If new element has a defined key:

```
$people['newkey'] = 'newvalue';
```

Without any defined key:

```
$people[] = 'newvalue';
```

Answer (score 0):

Array push but without key

```
array_push($people,'mark');
```

with key

```
$people['keytest'] = test;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `array_push` will not work because there is not next index.
What you can do is:

```
$people['new_key'] = 'new_value';
```

But it will replace the old value with same key if exist. So you can handle it with `isset` function.

```
if(isset($people['new_key'])){
    // do some stuff here!
}
else{
    $people['new_key'] = 'new_value';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using

```
$people[] = array($num->textContent => $name->textContent);
```

Comment: By writing above code you just changed the structure of `$people` array. Now it will look like:

array( array("key1" => "value1"), array("key2","value2"));

just `var_dump($people)` OR `print_r($people)`