# Setting text outside of php loop

Tags: php, html, loops

I am stuck on a possibly very simple thing...just can't figure it out. I have this: `echo "Pending Friends Are - " . $pending_friend_1 . "<br>";` in my loop. I need the `$pending_friend_1` to be within the loop while outputting it, otherwise I do not get my full loop of results. How can I take out the text `Pending Friends Are -` so that is still pieced together with the list. I am trying to do something like this:

Pending Friends Are -

Bob

George

Etc

```
    <div id="main">
<?php
//Display pending friends
    $friends_pending_sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM friends
        WHERE friend_two = ?
        AND status = ?
    ";
    $pending_friend_count_stmt = $con->prepare($friends_pending_sql);
    $pending_friend_count_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $status_one));
    $pending_friend_rows = $pending_friend_count_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo '<div id="pending-request_count">Total Pending Friends -' . $total_pending_count . '</div>';
    foreach ($pending_friend_rows as $pending_friend_row) {
        $pending_friend_1           = $pending_friend_row['friend_one'];
        $pending_friend_2           = $pending_friend_row['friend_two'];
        $pending_friend_status      = $pending_friend_row['status'];
        $pending_friend_status_date = $pending_friend_row['date'];
        $total_pending_friends      = $pending_friend_1 . "<br>" . $pending_friend_2;

        if ($pending_friend_2 == $user_id) {

            echo "Pending Friends Are - " . $pending_friend_1 . "<br>";
        }
        else if ($pending_friend_1 = $user_id) {
            echo "Friend Requests waiting for approval - " . $total_requests_sent_count . "<br>";
        }
    }
    echo $friend_status_button;
    echo $profile_viewer_message;
?>
```

Comment: You could save all results into an array and print them in your desired output.

Comment: @Manikiran Could you show me a basic concept or point me towards an online example?

Comment: You can do something like this.
$pending_friends = array();
foreach($desired_array as $key => $value){
  $pending_friends[] = $value . '<br>';
}

print_r($pending_friends);

Comment: You can look at this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676677/how-to-add-elements-to-an-empty-array-in-php

Comment: Please fix this error- else if ($pending_friend_1 = $user_id) { is an assignment and not a comparision... It needs == or === if you are matching value and type.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Thanks! Didn't catch that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert to an array

```
$friends_pending_arr[]=$pending_friend_1;
```

Then show outside the loop

```
   echo "Pending Friends Are - <br>";
   echo implode("<br>",$friends_pending_arr);
```

Full Code

```
<div id="main">
<?php
//Display pending friends
    $friends_pending_sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM friends
        WHERE friend_two = ?
        AND status = ?
    ";
    $pending_friend_count_stmt = $con->prepare($friends_pending_sql);
    $pending_friend_count_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $status_one));
    $pending_friend_rows = $pending_friend_count_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo '<div id="pending-request_count">Total Pending Friends -' . $total_pending_count . '</div>';
    foreach ($pending_friend_rows as $pending_friend_row) {
        $pending_friend_1           = $pending_friend_row['friend_one'];
        $pending_friend_2           = $pending_friend_row['friend_two'];
        $pending_friend_status      = $pending_friend_row['status'];
        $pending_friend_status_date = $pending_friend_row['date'];
        $total_pending_friends      = $pending_friend_1 . "<br>" . $pending_friend_2;

        if ($pending_friend_2 == $user_id) {

            $friends_pending_arr[]=$pending_friend_1;
        }
        else if ($pending_friend_1 == $user_id) {
            echo "Friend Requests waiting for approval - " . $total_requests_sent_count . "<br>";
        }
    }

    echo "Pending Friends Are - <br>";
    echo implode("<br>",$friends_pending_arr);

    echo $friend_status_button;
    echo $profile_viewer_message;
?>
```

Comment: Is implode a better method to use rather than another foreach?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$friends_pending_arr=array();
$friends_pending_sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM friends
    WHERE friend_two = ?
    AND status = ?
";
$pending_friend_count_stmt = $con->prepare($friends_pending_sql);
$pending_friend_count_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $status_one));
$pending_friend_rows = $pending_friend_count_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo '<div id="pending-request_count">Total Pending Friends -' . $total_pending_count . '</div>';
foreach ($pending_friend_rows as $pending_friend_row) {
    $pending_friend_1           = $pending_friend_row['friend_one'];
    $pending_friend_2           = $pending_friend_row['friend_two'];
    $pending_friend_status      = $pending_friend_row['status'];
    $pending_friend_status_date = $pending_friend_row['date'];
    $total_pending_friends      = $pending_friend_1 . "<br>" . $pending_friend_2;

    if ($pending_friend_2 == $user_id) {
        $friends_pending_arr[]=$pending_friend_1;
    }
    else if ($pending_friend_1 == $user_id) {
        echo "Friend Requests waiting for approval - " . $total_requests_sent_count . "<br>";
    }
}
echo "Pending Friends Are - ";
foreach($friends_pending_arr as $friend){echo $friend . "<br>";}
```

Comment: I get undefined $friend and it throws and error for the foreach you added.

Comment: @Manikiran , you might want to also fix the incorrect comparison in the else if ($pending_friend_1 = $user_id) { :) Seems everyone has missed that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is either an intentional code or a potential bug on the `else` branch of your Code, within the `foreach` Loop.  `else if ($pending_friend_1 = $user_id) {` is more an assignment than a check for equality. Perhaps the code below  - which is essentially your code: with a few minor tweaks - could help.

```
<?php
    // OBSERVE THAT THE GLOBAL PART OF YOUR PHP WAS MOVED OUT
    // FROM THE DIV... YOU DON'T NEED IT WITHIN A HTML DIV

    // CREATE A STRING TO HOLD PENDING FRIENDS.
    $strPendingFriends          = "";
    $friends_pending_sql        = "
        SELECT *
        FROM friends
        WHERE friend_two = ?
        AND status = ?
    ";
    $pending_friend_count_stmt  = $con->prepare($friends_pending_sql);
    $pending_friend_count_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $status_one));
    $pending_friend_rows        = $pending_friend_count_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<div id="main">
    <?php if($total_pending_count){ ?>
    <!-- Display pending friends -->
    <div id="pending-request_count">Total Pending Friends - <?php echo $total_pending_count; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php
        foreach ($pending_friend_rows as $pending_friend_row) {
            $pending_friend_1           = $pending_friend_row['friend_one'];
            $pending_friend_2           = $pending_friend_row['friend_two'];
            $pending_friend_status      = $pending_friend_row['status'];
            $pending_friend_status_date = $pending_friend_row['date'];
            $total_pending_friends      = $pending_friend_1 . "<br>" . $pending_friend_2;

            if ($pending_friend_2 == $user_id) {
                $strPendingFriends     .= "Pending Friends Are - " . $pending_friend_1 . "<br>";
            }else if ($pending_friend_1  == $user_id) {  //<== USED '==' THAN '='               
                $strPendingFriends     .= "Friend Requests waiting for approval - " . $total_requests_sent_count . "<br>";
            }
            echo $strPendingFriends;

        }
        echo $friend_status_button;
        echo $profile_viewer_message;
    ?>
</div>
```