# How to make Array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to make an array.I have array like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id_facility_master] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id_facility_master] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id_facility_master] => 6
    ))
```

It's returned from codeigniter active record
so i want change format by the array values like this

$arr = array(2,3,6);

Comment: use `array_column($yourArray,'id_facility_master')`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676677/how-to-add-elements-to-an-empty-array-in-php

Answer (score 1):

you can use array_column

```
$results= array_column($yourarray, 'id_facility_master');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function

```
function generate($arr){
   return $arr['id_facility_master'];
}

$res = array_map('generate', $data)
```