# How to send a variable from a foreach loop to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, variables, foreach

I have a foreach loop that searches through files and creates arrays for that files and it all works as intended. In the foreach loop I create a $total variable adding a set amount of the values in that loop to each other. I would like to add all of the $total's at the end of my code, which I figure could be achieved by sending each $total automatically to a seperate array outside the loop, and then using an array_sum() function, but I'm struggling. Here is an example of my code -->

```
<?php

foreach($file as $client) {

    $name = $client;

    $document = "client/" . $name . "";



    $client_data = file_get_contents($document);

    $data = explode("\t",$client_data_);


$total = $data[0] + $data[1] + $data[2] + $data[3];

}

?>
```

**And then of course to send that $total to an array to add together... I have no clue on how to do this... any tips/solutions?**

Apologies if this is ignorant, or badly worded.. I'm a student and relatively new to the coding stuff (and want to get good marks).

Comment: i think you just want `$total += $data[0] + $data[1] + $data[2] + $data[3];`

Comment: and define `$total = 0` before the loop, otherwise, PHP will complain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add elements to an empty array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676677/how-to-add-elements-to-an-empty-array-in-php)

Comment: quite anti-climactic but does the job! thanks very much - also yes apologies if this had been asked already, i'd looked but nothing seemed to work for me, probabaly my ignorance... thanks for the solve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a `$temporary_total` variable to hold the total of the items within the array first, then add it to the `$final_total`

```
<?php

$final_total = 0;

foreach($file as $client) {
 $name = $client;
 $document = "client/" . $name . "";
 $client_data = file_get_contents($document);
 $data = explode("\t",$client_data_);
 $temporary_total = $data[0] + $data[1] + $data[2] + $data[3];

 $final_total = $final_total + $temporary_total; //adding your sum of $temporary_total to the $finaltotal

 }

echo $final_total;

?>
```

Comment: perfect! both tim's and yours work great, life-saver! i've used this in my code now - appreciate it

Comment: happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$total = 0;

foreach($file as $client) {
    $name = $client;
    $document = "client/" . $name . "";
    $client_data = file_get_contents($document);
    $data = explode("\t",$client_data_);
    $total += $data[0] + $data[1] + $data[2] + $data[3];
}

echo $total;
```