# how to push data into array using array_push in php

Tags: php

I am developing a simple online shop cart page using php and xml I have a issue while appending data to array. The working is that when we click on add to cart the id should append to an array and store in session variable:

```
<?php session_start(); 
if(!isset($_POST['addtocart']))
{
    $_SESSION["array1"] =array();
    array_push($_SESSION["array1"],$_GET["pid"]);   
    print_r($_SESSION["array1"]);
}
?>
```

It is not appending id only showing the id of the product that I clicked

Comment: You're re-initialising `$_SESSION["array1"]` every time you run the code. Change that line to `if (!isset($_SESSION["array1"])) $_SESSION["array1"] =array();`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add elements to an empty array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676677/how-to-add-elements-to-an-empty-array-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one.

```
session_start(); 
if( !isset($_POST['addtocart']) )
{
 if( !isset($_SESSION['array1']) ) $_SESSION["array1"] =array();
 $_SESSION['array1'][] = $_GET['pid']; 
}
print_r($_SESSION["array1"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work well

```
<?php session_start(); 
$data = array();
if(!isset($_POST['addtocart']))
{
array_push($data, $_GET["pid"], "test", "more data");   
print_r($data);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can short using array_push to session

```
$_SESSION['addtocart'][ ]=$_GET['pid'];
```