# Put on array a foreach using blade

Tags: php, laravel-blade

I would like to put a *foreach* to an array using blade in laravel, below is what I have attempted and no success

```
@foreach($lists as $list) 
<? $tags = $list->name ?>
@endforeach

<?php
$arr = array($tags);
?>
```

> The result to the code above is:

```
$arr = array(name1);
```

> I would like to get is:

```
$arr = array('name1', 'name2', 'name3', ...);
```

I'm using laravel 5.4

Comment: Put `$arr[] = $tags;` inside your `@foreach`

Comment: I would suggest handling this in the controller as opposed to the view

Comment: @Juakali92 how could I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add elements to an empty array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676677/how-to-add-elements-to-an-empty-array-in-php)

Comment: Or better is `$arr = array_column($lists, "name");` and do it in your controller.

Comment: Thanks everybody! now it is working with answer of @kgbph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be

```
@foreach($lists as $list) 
    <? $tags[] = $list->name ?>
@endforeach
```

> I would like to get is:
>
> $arr = array('name1', 'name2', 'name3', ...);

Set `$arr = $tags`

Answer (score 0):

check out array_push to push array at [array_push() method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)