# Why does this way of adding values to an array in php work?

Tags: php, arrays

I use something like

```
$data = [];
foreach (){
  $data[] = $api_content;
}
return $data;
```

the $data array does not get overwritten. Instead the values of $api_content get appended.

Is that right??? Why? I thought it gets overwritten....

Comment: You are adding to the array - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676677/how-to-add-elements-to-an-empty-array-in-php

Comment: It is syntactic sugar for array_push (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

Comment: `if no key is specified, the maximum of the existing int indices is taken, and the new key will be that maximum value plus 1 (but at least 0). If no int indices exist yet, the key will be 0 (zero).` see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: `$data[] = $api_content` appends, whereas `$data = $api_content` overwrites, and you lose the array structure in the process.