# Printing looped user input from an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, readline

I'm making a small program that saves user input into an array an then prints the array, But I only get the last input printed each time. I'm using readline and php.eol because it has to work in the cmd.

```
<?php

echo "Hoeveel activiteiten wil je toevoegen?" . PHP_EOL;
$hoeveel = readline();
if (is_numeric($hoeveel)) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $hoeveel; $i++) {
        echo "Wat wil je toevoegen aan je bucketlist?" . PHP_EOL;
        $entry *= $i;
        $entry = readline() . PHP_EOL;
        $bucketlist = array($entry, $entry, $entry);
    }
    echo "In jouw bucketlist staat: " . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($bucketlist as $key) {
        echo $value;
    }
} else {
    exit($hoeveel . ' is geen getal, probeer het opnieuw');
}
?>
```

I've tried in it an associative array but it seems it should be possible in a normal array.

Comment: I don't understand your `$entry *= $i` are you multiplying with zero? and then overwriting it immidietly after?

Comment: `$bucketlist = ...` will overwrite on each iteration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add elements to an empty array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676677/how-to-add-elements-to-an-empty-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store each value from `readline()` into `$bucketlist` and then loop the values from it.

- Note that in your code there is no `echo $value;`
- this part can be removed `$entry *= $i;` as it is immediately overwritten and it also does not exist yet

Example:

```
echo "Hoeveel activiteiten wil je toevoegen?" . PHP_EOL;
$hoeveel = readline();
$bucketlist = [];

if (is_numeric($hoeveel)) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $hoeveel; $i++) {
        echo "Wat wil je toevoegen aan je bucketlist?" . PHP_EOL;
        $bucketlist[] = readline() . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo "In jouw bucketlist staat: " . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($bucketlist as $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
} else {
    exit($hoeveel . ' is geen getal, probeer het opnieuw');
}
```