# Retrieve an array of invoices instead of an object PHP

Tags: php, chargebee

I'm trying to retrieve a list of invoices per customer. So far I'm only retrieving the first object of the list. But how do I retrieve the whole list? I'm a beginner in PHP so I really can't figure this out and the docs of Chargebee aren't clarifying anything for me.

Here are the docs:
https://apidocs.eu.chargebee.com/docs/api/invoices?prod_cat_ver=2&lang=php#list_invoices

And this is what I tried so far:

```
$customerID = $_POST['customerID']; 

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/chargebee-php-2.8.3/lib/ChargeBee.php');

ChargeBee_Environment::configure("xxxx","xxxx");

$result = ChargeBee_Invoice::all(array(
  "limit" => 13,
  "sortBy[desc]" => "date",
  "customerId[is]" => (string)$customerID
  ));
  
foreach($result as $entry){
  $invoice = $entry->invoice();
}

$array = (array) $invoice;

echo json_encode($array);
```

Unfortunately I'm only retrieving the first item of the list. How do I get the whole list in an array, but encoded to a json string?

Comment: You are only assiging one invoice to `$invoice`. You need to create an array and append them - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676677/how-to-add-elements-to-an-empty-array-in-php)

Comment: @DarkBee This works. But the output is not as expected. Before I get the output of the invoice. Now I get an array with empty objects in it. Ex: [{}, {}, {}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep overwriting your `$invoice` variable.

Creating and empty array and pushing every invoice onto that should yield the result you want. So try this:

```
$customerID = $_POST['customerID']; 

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/chargebee-php-2.8.3/lib/ChargeBee.php');

ChargeBee_Environment::configure("xxxx","xxxx");

$result = ChargeBee_Invoice::all(array(
  "limit" => 13,
  "sortBy[desc]" => "date",
  "customerId[is]" => (string)$customerID
  ));

$invoicesArr = [] // create empty array
  
foreach($result as $entry){
  array_push($invoicesArr, $entry->invoice()); // foreach invoice, push it to array
}

echo json_encode($invoicesArr);
```

Comment: This works. But the output is not as expected. Before I get the output of the invoice. Now I get an array with empty objects in it. Ex: [{}, {}, {}]

Comment: What does `var_dump($entry->invoice())` return? In order to be able to use `json_encode` properly on an object, that said object needs to implement [JsonSerializable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php)

Comment: @user2598506 checkout @DarkBee 's comment. I think if you `var_dump($invoicesArr)` before your `echo json_encode(..)` you would see an array of invoices.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `getValues()` function given by chargebee. Here is the example.

```
$result = ChargeBee_Invoice::all(array(
 "limit" => 13,
 "sortBy[desc]" => "date",
 "customerId[is]" => (string)$customerID
));

if (count($result) > 0) {

   $invoices = [];

   foreach ($result as $value) {

       $invoices[] = $value->invoice()->getValues();

   }

   echo json_encode($invoices);

} else {

   echo "Invoices not found";

}
```